# Selecting all the tables containing specific columns

Tags: mysql

I have around 300 tables in my database . I want the tablenames containing tha columns sname,dtcreatedat,dtmodifiedat,ixlastmodifiedby and fstatus . Presently I am checking manually each of the table. Which command can be used in mysql to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find all tables containing that columns with:

```
select distinct table_name
from information_schema.columns
where column_name in ('sname','dtcreatedat','dtmodifiedat','ixlastmodifiedby','fstatus')
and table_schema = 'your_db_name'
```

Comment: This will retrieve the tables from all the databases. If I want to retrive the tables from a particular database then ?

Comment: then add `and table_schema = 'db_name'`. I updated the answer.